# What is the use of Form Data in inspect element of an API?

Tags: javascript

I found an API in inspect element on a website and i scrolled down to see "Form Data" at the bottom after I clicked the API.
In "Form Data" it had an object with some things in already.
How could I use it?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific, what website, where in the console, how did you find "an API" etc. right now this makes little sense

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you elaborate on your question with more specific information?